# Android studio hang on "Gradle build running" on windows 7 machine

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I have an app that I am working on in Android studio and I have updated Android studio yesterday. Now when I open Android-Studio it hangs on "Gradle Build running" and I have all my R. red for almost an hour. I am running windows 7 64-bit and have around a dozen aapt.exe processes open.

What I have tried so far,

1. Exit and restart AS
2. Invalidate Caches and Restart
3. File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Gradle check/uncheck

> Offline work

all to no avail. Can someone point me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle will download any dependencies it needs**, for Studio, this could be considered due to which may take long time.

May be possible that where these dependencies are trying to go in your file system is somehow *write-protected*,

Try doing : (for windows)

**File --> Settings --> HTTP Proxy(Search for http proxy) and set to "None".**

[image]

Comment: i can't find this setting in Android Studio ?

Comment: Go to file --> setting --> search for HTTP proxy and set to none.

Comment: do you get that ? @umerk44

Comment: I couldn't find that either. Where is setting is that?

Comment: what os and android-studio version you are using ?

Comment: Android Studio 1.5.1 on windows 7.

Comment: Found it. I was not doing the search thing. But it is set to no proxy by default. Meaning the behavior was being exhibited while that was in place. There must be another explanation to it. Thanks for your help.