# Gradle is wasting my time

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Sometimes Gradle gets stuck and it starts run forever. When I face that situation i do these

**1.** I try to stop the gradle using cross button from the button it doesn't stop and stuck here too showing "Stopping gradle..."

**2.** I also try to stop it from command line gradle --stop but doesn't work.

**3.** So finally I close it from the task manager because if I try to close it from the Android studio it goes to not responding state.

I start the Android Studio again and gradle build failed with the error **"Another gradle process is running, it's lock"**. *Sorry I forget the exact error message but something like that but i think you will get the idea if you are android developer it's very common error*. If I restart the computer it solves that problem.

So the every time gradle got stuck, I have to restart the computer to start my development again.

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35763608/2826147).

Comment: So, this is a complaint letter to Gradle? I don't have such problem. Maybe it's better for you to provide Android Studio as well as Gradle version.

Comment: @Raptor Yeah i should i observe many people are facing these type of problem with gradle

Answer (score 2):

So after trying so many tricks nothing was working for me gradle build was still freezing very frequently than i unistall the ***Avast Antivirus***. Now after that my gradle build never stuck. It was avast antivirus that was messing with gradle build. 
Hope this can help someone

Comment: Looks similar to the problem I had with my builds once, and it turned out to be caused by Charles running on my machine. There should be a way to configure Avast to not block the connections Gradle makes to the repository, in case you still want to use Avast.

Comment: @Egor Yeah there should be but believe me i am so happy after uninstalling Avast,  gradle build is super fast now

Answer (score 0):

For developing `IDE` like `android-studio` need lots of system resources. And if you don't have an `android device` with you, then you need to use the `emulator` to `debug`(test) you `app`, which in turn leads to more resource consumption. If your `machine` is more powerful it won't be a problem, but if it is not, I suggest you to use any `linux distro` than developing `android apps` in `windows platform` and see how performance increases.